# Compare the area of domains A and B?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> The logo opposite is constituted by two semicircles and by a quarter
>   circle. Compare the area of domains A and B

[image]

I tried to compare the area of one of the semicircles to the area of a quarter of circles, to be able to express this relation according to areas A, B and C but with no luck

- Is there any way to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

If the diameter of semicircles is $d$, and C, A, B are the areas of the regions indicated by these letters, we have:

$
2C+A+B=\frac{\pi}{4}d^2
$
because this is the area of a quarter of a circle of radius $r=d$

$
C+A=\frac{\pi}{8}d^2
$
because this is the area of a semicircle of radius $\frac{1}{2}d$

so
$$
2C+2A=2C+A+B
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: 2C+2A=2C+A+B so A=B ?

Comment: Is it necessary to take d=1 in order to solve that problem if we don't take it as 1 we can't solve it am i wrong ?

Comment: Yes: $A=B$ and I take $d=1$ because this result does not depend from the value of $d$ . Can you see why?

Comment: @Educ: Now you  can see the answer with any value of the diameter

Comment: I still can't see why ? would please elaborate one more time

Comment: See the answer. Now the value of $d$ is not specified.

Comment: Thank you I will be back to your solution later for any question  Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome! and don't forget to accept if  the answer is useful for you.

Comment: Of course I will once I'll finish some stuff